# Дана многомерная структура - вывести элементы. как обратиться к пустому объекту не имеющему ключа?

Tags: javascript

Задача:
Дано:

```js
let data = [
    {
        1: [
            'data111',
            'data112',
            'data113',
        ],
        2: [
            'data121',
            'data122',
            'data123',
        ],
    },
    {
        1: [
            'data211',
            'data212',
            'data213',
        ],
        2: [
            'data221',
            'data222',
            'data223',
        ],
    },
    {
        1: [
            'data411',
            'data412',
            'data413',
        ],
        2: [
            'data421',
            'data422',
            'data423',
        ],
    },
];
```

Вывести в консоль элементы.

При выводе в `console.log(key);` в первом цикле = вывод:

```json
{
  "1": [
    "data411",
    "data412",
    "data413"
  ],
  "2": [
    "data421",
    "data422",
    "data423"
  ]
}
```

А при выводе `console.log(data[key])` = `undefined`.

почему? что сделала не так?

и как обратиться к пустому объекту не имеющему ключа??

Код:

```js
for (let key of data) {

    for (let subKey in data[key]) {

        let obj = data[key];
        for (let name of obj) {

            console.log(name)

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вам нужно использовать не `of` в циклах, а везде `in`.

Comment: @PeterKolosov можете обьснить пожалуйста почему?

Comment: Ок, напишу ответ

Comment: А вам нужно чтобы что выводилось?

Comment: @PeterKolosov все елементы. решила. могли бы ли вы пожалуйста взглянуть? исправлю сейчас. + я так и не поняла почему нужно использовать везде in?? но это работает. также я думала что это 3хмерная структура но нет. оказывается 2х мерная..

Comment: Всё, ответ написал.

Comment: @KateBlbn, вы уже задавали точно такой же вопрос с точно такой же проблемой. В чем отличие между вопросами?

Comment: @Grundy это 2 разных вопроса по одной теме. там создавался обьект из массивов. здесь нужно изьять элементы из многомерной структуры. разве это одно и тоже? да. тема одна - но я думала что данный сайт для того и создан чтоб помогать разобраться в непонятных вещах ;)

Comment: @KateBlbn, обрати внимание, что в обоих вопросах ты неверно используешь цикл `for..of`. Не важно что ты пытаешься сделать с массивами, если у тебя ошибка именно в неверном использовании цикла.

Comment: @Grundy вы правы. Благодарю  пошла разбираться. ☀️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оператор `of` в JavaScript итерирует не ключи, а значения.
Поэтому, в вашем случае можно сделать так, с помощью `in`:

```js
for (let key in data) {
    for (let subKey in data[key]) {
        let obj = data[key];
        
        for (let name in obj) {
            console.log(name)
        }
    }
}
```

Я улучшил форматирование кода, потому что в текущем виде его сложно читать.

Для того, чтобы выводились элементы, а не ключи, можно сделать так:

```js
for (let key in data) {
    for (let subKey in data[key]) {
        let obj = data[key];
        
        for (let name in obj) {
            console.log(obj[name])
        }
    }
}
```

Если что-то непонятно, спрашивайте.

Comment: Ответ понравился? Проголосуйте за (Поставьте плюсик).

Comment: поставила галочку. Благодарю за помощь.

Comment: Упрашивать не буду, но можете ещё поставить стрелочку вверх))

Comment: Done. Для добрых людей ничего не жалко ;)

Comment: =] о, спасибо))

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста ;)

Comment: Да ну, минус без явной причины?

Answer (score 0):

```
let data = [
    {
        1: [
            'data111',
            'data112',
            'data113',
        ],
        2: [
            'data121',
            'data122',
            'data123',
        ],
    },
    {
        1: [
            'data211',
            'data212',
            'data213',
        ],
        2: [
            'data221',
            'data222',
            'data223',
        ],
    },
    {
        1: [
            'data411',
            'data412',
            'data413',
        ],
        2: [
            'data421',
            'data422',
            'data423',
        ],
    },
],
    subObj = 0,
    obj = 0;
for ( let key in data ) {
subObj = data[key];
for ( let subKey in subObj ) {
 obj = subObj[subKey]; 
console.log(obj)
}
}
```